# How to disable PowerPoint shape?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

Is it possible to disable a PowerPoint Shape?

"disable" here I mean this shape cannot be selected, cannot be moved, cut, copied, etc...

I am using Visual Studio 2013, C#

Comment: PowerPoint is a editor tool to create a presentation. It would be bad if an editor could not edit what has been stored within the presentation.

Comment: you make a point here.